# Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached Error

Tags: matlab, matrix, simulation, mathematical-optimization

I'm having this problem in Matlab: Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached as one of functions is being called a lot. This is really frustrating. There is a lot about this problem on the web. But I've looked very well and there is no single real solution to this problem. Even increasing the Recursion Limit using  set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) does not help because after I do that and run my code, Matlab crashes (and it crashes for any value N Ii put)

FYI, my code is supposed to call one of the functions way more than 500 times, so there is nothing wrong with it. So is there any way to increase the recursion limit on Matlab (without having it crashing) or better make it with no limit?

Comment: could you maybe post code or the name of the function that recurses 500 times?

Answer (score 1):

To say there is NOTHING wrong with a 500-fold recursion may be wrong in itself.

A problem with recursion is MATLAB must set up separate workspaces each time a function is called, building up a stack of them. This can be quite inefficient, using up a fair amount of time as well as memory. So there may well be something wrong with what you are doing.

As well, very often I've seen that recursive functions can be re-written to be NOT recursive. Techniques like memoization can be employed to avoid recursively evaluating a function on the same inputs many times over. Why do the same computations more than once?

You CAN change limits on the stack size, but very often those limits are quite reasonable, and are put there to prevent memory and time problems. So you Are far better off looking seriously at your code to decide if such a change is appropriate rather than reformulating your problem.

For example, you CAN compute factorials using recursion, but why bother? This is an extremely silly solution when a simple loop is far more efficient. The overhead of stacks is far more than you want to expend when a loop is ample for the problem.

Another example is the Fibonacci sequence. It can be written recursively, which is an easy thing to do, but that does not make it at all a good thing to do. Computed fully recursively, the n'th Fibonacci number will require exponential time and memory to compute F(n). Loops are better, which allow you to do O(n) amount of work. Even better yet, memoization schemes coupled with the proper identities allow computation of F(n) in O(log2(n)) time.

The point is, you CAN solve many problems with recursion, but that does not mean this is the right way to do so.

Comment: "For example, you CAN compute factorials using recursion, but why bother? This is an extremely silly solution when a simple loop is far more efficient."

Answer (score 1):

Problems:Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N) to change the limit. Be
aware that exceeding your available stack space can crash MATLAB and/or your computer.
Programme:

```
puma560;
robot=p560
N=5; % Numero de Iteraciones
z=linspace(0.432,0.482,N); % se mueve 0.05 unidades
x=zeros(1,N);
y=x;
for j=1:N
y(1,j)=-0.15;
x(1,j)=0.452;
end
phi=zeros(1,N);
for k=1:length(z)
phik=phi(k);
T(:,:,k)=[cos(phik) -sin(phik) 0 x(k); 
          sin(phik) cos(phik) 0 y(k); 
          0 0 1 z(k);
          0 0 0 1];
end
qzz=ikine(robot,T)
plot(robot,qzz)

y=linspace(-0.15,0.05,N); % se mueve 0.20 unidades
x=zeros(1,N);
z=x;
for j=1:N
x(1,j)=0.452;
z(1,j)=0.482;
end
phi=zeros(1,N);
for k=1:length(y)
phik=phi(k);
T(:,:,k)=[cos(phik) -sin(phik) 0 x(k); 
          sin(phik) cos(phik) 0 y(k);
          0 0 1 z(k);
          0 0 0 1];
end
qyy=ikine(robot,T)
plot(robot,qyy)

x=linspace(0.452,0.702,N); % se mueve 0.25 unidades
y=zeros(1,N);
z=y;
for j=1:N
y(1,j)=0.05;
z(1,j)=0.482;
end
phi=zeros(1,N);
for k=1:length(x)
phik=phi(k);
T(:,:,k)=[cos(phik) -sin(phik) 0 x(k);
          sin(phik) cos(phik) 0 y(k);
          0 0 1 z(k);
          0 0 0 1];
end
qxx=ikine(robot,T)
plot(robot,qxx)

y=linspace(0.05,-0.05,N); % se mueve 0.10 unidades
x=zeros(1,N);
z=x;
for j=1:N
x(1,j)=0.702;
z(1,j)=0.482;
end
phi=zeros(1,N);
for k=1:length(y)
phik=phi(k);
T(:,:,k)=[cos(phik) -sin(phik) 0 x(k);
          sin(phik) cos(phik) 0 y(k);
          0 0 1 z(k);
          0 0 0 1];
end
qyy=ikine(robot,T)
plot(robot,qyy)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try increasing the stack size used by MATLAB, since recursion typically breaks once the stack is full.

Take note that there is a fundamental difference between a function that *gets called* 500 times and a function that *recurses* 500 times. In MATLAB, the latter is quite rare. Are you sure you need this recursion?

Comment: @woodchips....I know it's normal to visit this file more than 500 times because this is how the algorithm works (read about Pohst  Enumeration if you're interested
It's not an error bcoz the stack is getting filled! this error occurs bcoz matlab is assuming it's stuck in a loop...while it is not

This error does not occur in C or Java....Anyways....thanks a lot guys...it seems like I have to write my cood using loops instead of calling files.

Comment: @user2329321 - why respond on THIS answer, instead of the one I gave? Anyway, don't argue that the code is doing something normal. The fact that the problem arises means there IS an issue. You can't argue with a computer. It MAY mean your code is wrongly implemented. It MAY mean that your choice of implementation is poor.

Comment: @woodchips....I'm sorry I replied here. I was in a hurry and didn't notice where I was typing. Anyways, I really don't understand why you're insisting on your point. Again, read about the Pohst Enumeration algorithm to understand why it's normal. And by the way, I implemented the algorithm again and the same part is still being run MORE than 500 times and I'm not getting that error. The only difference is that I wrote the code this time with nested loops instead of calling the codes in other files, which is of course a bit more complex. Aanyways, thanks for the help and informative feedback.